# Error: write devicemapper docker load : no space left on device

Tags: docker, suse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MJWu.png)

my operation is SUSE12.1, it's new， I just set up it
I have changed my docker root path to /home,there is a lot of space
but when I docker load -i one_image.tar(this tar is 16G, can not be smaller)
it said:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B5ur.png)
that was bothering me for a very long time(nearly 40hours)

I can docker load this tar at other system like centos7,
I cannot change operation,and cannot get a small tar， but I want to load it. I have successed once, but I reset the operation for other reason
who can help me pleaseeeeeeeeeeeee
here is my docker info
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBKig.png)

and here is my df -h
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wwAg.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: According to your kernel version (3.12.28-4-default) you're running a SLES 12 GM version - not SP1. Please note that SLES 12 is out of support since 2016 (or 2019 if LTSS was used) and your kernel is even from 2014. You should consider upgrading to an active release because you're missing important security and bugfix updates.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why did you change the docker root path (and how)? Does loading the image work if you're using the standard setup?